# Operation is not a Member of Service Reference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service

I am learning to create a new service reference for a Form I am writing in VB. When I type the reference like so:

```
ServiceReference.Operation
```

I get an error that says "'Operation' is not a member of 'Service Reference'"
What am i doing wrong?
Here is the code.
Service

```
Public Class Service
    Implements IService

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetChargeAmount(ByRef d As Double) As Double Implements IService.GetChargeAmount
        Return 200.0 * (d * 60)
    End Function

End Class
```

Interface

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetChargeAmount(ByRef d As Double) As Double

End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property BoolValue() As Boolean
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property StringValue() As String

End Class
```

Calling Code

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        If (tbGroup.Text = "" Or tbMinutes.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all necesary information")
            ClearText()
        Else
            Dim dMoney As Double = 0.0
            dMoney = ChargeReference.GetChargeAmount(Double.Parse(tbMinutes.Text))
            tbTotalCharge.Text = dMoney.ToString("C")



    End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting

Comment: If it is a service reference, you need to use the "client" class that is generated. For example: `Using myservice = new ServiceClient()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call the method for the service operation using the namespace of the service reference rather than its `ServiceClient` class - i.e. `ChargeReference.GetChargeAmount` rather than `ChargeReference.ServiceClient.GetChargeAmount`.

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    If (tbGroup.Text = "" Or tbMinutes.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all necessary information")
        ClearText()
    Else
        Dim dMoney As Double = 0.0
        Dim serviceClient = New ChargeReference.ServiceClient() ' Instantiate the service client.
        dMoney = serviceClient.GetChargeAmount(Double.Parse(tbMinutes.Text))
        tbTotalCharge.Text = dMoney.ToString("C")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you look at the code generated for ChargeReference, the distinction is pretty clear.  I have added a few comments for extra clarity:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18408
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


'
' NOTE: namespace named the same as the service reference in Solution Explorer
'
Namespace ChargeReference

    <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"),  _
     System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName:="ChargeReference.IService")>  _
    Public Interface IService

        <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetChargeAmount", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetChargeAmountResponse")>  _
        Function GetChargeAmount(ByRef d As Double) As Double
    End Interface

    <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Public Interface IServiceChannel
        Inherits ChargeReference.IService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    End Interface

    '
    ' NOTE: generated ServiceClient class through which to use the service reference
    '
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Partial Public Class ServiceClient
        Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of ChargeReference.IService)
        Implements ChargeReference.IService

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String)
            MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String, ByVal remoteAddress As String)
            MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String, ByVal remoteAddress As System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)
            MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal binding As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, ByVal remoteAddress As System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)
            MyBase.New(binding, remoteAddress)
        End Sub

        '
        ' NOTE: generated service-client (instance) method through which to call the service operation
        '
        Public Function GetChargeAmount(ByRef d As Double) As Double Implements ChargeReference.IService.GetChargeAmount
            Return MyBase.Channel.GetChargeAmount(d)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: You rock man. I Googled til my hands fell off for that one. I am usually a Java guy so VB throws me off a little when i work with it.

Comment: Thanks.  Happy to help, and glad it is working for you now.  ["No, you rock.  When are you gonna drop Magnum on us, buddy?"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196229/quotes?item=qt0375870) :D